# Close questions: no number next to the option

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

I've noticed this problem several times, I'm not sure if it's a bug though.

When I review the close votes, sometimes when I click the close button I can't see what the original closer has chosen as an option.

Most of the time you see a blue square with the number of close votes next to the option but sometimes there's nothing.

The only way I can see why the question is being closed is by clicking the `(more)` next to `This question has been flagged as:`

See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: not sure if this is a bug or a feature. I've seen in on other SE websites, even on stackoverflow. My guess is that is missing from time to time to not influence the closing decision. But it's just a guess. You can search for an answer or ask a question on http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow up on this, I ended up asking the question on Meta SE: [Close questions: no number next to the option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280274/close-questions-no-number-next-to-the-option/280275#280275)

So the number next to the option only shows up when the question is **voted to close** and does not show up when the question is **flagged**

**Flagged** are for people under 3k reputation.